# ANDROID STUDIO: Take picture with Camera API -> Send this picture to another activity

Tags: java, android, image, android-studio, bitmap

After I take a picture with the Camera API, this picture displays on the screen/this activity. I want to send this picture that covers the whole screen to another activity called PictureEditor. There I will add functionality that can edit the picture.

```
  // Code in MainActivity
  mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
  Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PictureEditor.class);
  Bitmap b = getBitmapFromView(mPreview);
  ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, bs);
  i.putExtra("byteArray", bs.toByteArray());
  startActivity(i);
```

In PictureEditor I have this code in OnCreate.

```
  // Code in PictureEditor
  if(getIntent().hasExtra("byteArray")) {
  ImageView previewThumbnail = new ImageView(this);
  Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
               getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray"),0,getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray").length);
        previewThumbnail.setImageBitmap(b);
    }
```

What can I do to retrive this picture in PictureEditor, and that this picture is the only thing that is visible on the screen in this activity? (Decode the bitmap and display it as an image on the screen)

Thanks for all kind of help!

Comment: Code looks fine. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `startActivity` call `startActivityForResult` and get the image from the bundle in `onActivityResult` call back method in the same activity and pass the image to the new `Activity`.

Comment: Thanks for answering! 
Just one question; How would this onActivityResult-method look like?

Comment: You can override onActivityResult method in the Activity, its a call back methods that's called when the activity called is completed its action. For more details look at the documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int, int, android.content.Intent)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Code in PictureEditor
  if(getIntent().hasExtra("byteArray")) {
  ImageView previewThumbnail = new ImageView(this);
  Bitmap b =(Bitmap) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("byteArray");
        previewThumbnail.setImageBitmap(b);
    }
```

But if you send information between activitys. The size of this information cant exceed 1 MB. You  have to compress your bitmap.